# NuxtJS - Running nuxtServerInit in parallel with asyncData in the page component

Tags: nuxt.js

In my `nuxtServerInit` action, I'm calling an external API to get a set of settings for the current application. When the request resolves, the settings are persisted to state. This action needs to be called in almost all of the cases. This is provided just as information, as the way Nuxt works is to call it every time.

In addition to that, in the page component, I'm calling the same api to get a list of Blog Posts, for example.

At the moment, when the request arrives, Nuxt calls the `nuxtServerInit` action, when that resolves, it proceeds to render the view.

This, however, causes both request to run in sequence, when they can actually run  in parallel ( they are independent of one another ).

In an attempt to improve the load time of the application, I'd like to somehow run these two in parallel, so that the rendering occurs once the `asyncData` and `nuxtServerInit` complete.

I tried to move the API call from `nuxtServerInit` to `fetch` in the layout component, but that one seems to wait for `asyncData` in the page component to resolve, so they still do not run in parallel.

Is there anything else that I can try?

Here's a minimal representation. Look into `pages/index.vue` and `store/index.js`
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-feather-rbknu?file=/pages/index.vue

`nuxtServerInit` action resolves after 5 seconds, and 5 seconds after that, `asyncData` resolves. I would like to figure out a way to reduce this to 5 seconds, from the current 10 seconds.

I'm looking for any way to accomplish this, even if its not the most elegant one ( hopefully it does not introduce a lot of boilerplate into all page components, like mixins ).

I looked into rendering a separate component, that when created, checks if data fetched from `nuxtServerInit` is available, and if not , it fetches it, then render that in the `layout` components, but it also didn't work.

Comment: Can you make it run in parallel in async data ? Can you share your code maybe ?

Comment: I can make it run in parallel, but asyncData runs in components, and I want this action to be executed automatically on the initial request. If I do it in asyncData, I would need to do it in every page component

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move the code from `nuxtServerInit` to the `asyncData`. Then store the fetched configuration in the vuex and check for already stored configuration before fetching it again. This way you don't fetch the configuration again with each route navigation in the future.

```
async asyncData ({ store }) {
  if (store.getters.configuration !== null) {
    // fetch config and your page data in parallel
  } else {
    // fetch page data only
  }
}
```

You can wrap the config fetching code in a function to not repeat it for each page.

Comment: I already said what's the problem with this. Even if its in a function, it still has to be called manually in every page component, which is highly undesirable

Comment: I don't know about a way how to have that perfect outcome here. Are you using a server-side cache ? If so, this shouldn't matter too much as only the first request has to wait for the whole rendering process.